# How can I remarshal a struct using the types of the struct and not the tags in go?

Tags: json, go, struct

I'd like to remarshal a struct to json and use the types definded in the struct for the output.
Structs:

```golang
type A struct{
B []B //edit: fields have to be exported to work
}

type B struct{
X string `json:"x"` //edit: fields have to be exported to work
Y float64 `json:"y,string"` //edit: fields have to be exported to work
Z float64 `json:"z,string"` //edit: fields have to be exported to work
```

If unmarshal with these structs I get B.y as a float64, as expected. But if I remarshal this again to a JSON I get the JSON I unmarshalled, with y and z as strings, but I want to get them as float64. I have to add the ',string' part because the API returns everything as string in the JSON responses (see example below). Do I have to write a custom marshal function to do this or can I just add json tags to the struct definition?

Example response and remarshaled json:

```
{
    "A": [
        {
            "x": "test1",
            "y": "1.00",
            "z": "1.01"
        },
        {
            "x": "test2",
            "y": "2.00",
            "z": "2.01"
        }
    ]
}
```

Expected remarshaled JSON:

```
{
    "A": [
        {
            "x": "test1",
            "y": 1.00,
            "z": 1.01
        },
        {
            "x": "test2",
            "y": 2.00,
            "z": 2.01
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't marshal or unmarshal these at all, because the fields are unexported. But to do what you're describing, just convert to an equivalent type with no (or different) struct tags. Because it's a nested slice you have to iterate it to do so.

```
func main() {
    a := A{}
    err := json.Unmarshal(corpus, &a)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    c := C{}
    for _, b := range a.B {
        c.B = append(c.B, D(b))
    }
    payload, _ := json.Marshal(c)
    fmt.Println(string(payload))
}

type A struct {
    B []B
}

type B struct {
    X string  `json:"x"`
    Y float64 `json:"y,string"`
    Z float64 `json:"z,string"`
}

type C struct {
    B []D
}

type D struct {
    X string  `json:"x"`
    Y float64 `json:"y"`
    Z float64 `json:"z"`
}
```

Working playground example: https://play.golang.org/p/pQTcg0RV_RL

Comment: Ah yes, you're completely right about the unexported fields. Thank you for your answer, everything works now